# Please assist in understanding random.choices() weighting

Tags: python

Hoping to get some help on understanding the weighting using random.choices()

```
import random
k = 100

population = random.choices(
population=[['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e'],['f'],['g'],['h'], ['i'],['j']],
weights=[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
k=k)

print(population.count(['a'])/k,
population.count(['b'])/k,
population.count(['c'])/k,
population.count(['d'])/k,
population.count(['e'])/k,
population.count(['f'])/k,
population.count(['g'])/k,
population.count(['h'])/k,
population.count(['i'])/k,
population.count(['j'])/k)
```

So I have been through several of the answers on this and my understanding is that this should be the formula when calculating the weighting for each string:

Total Weight is 100

a is 10/100 or 10%

b is 10/100 or 10%
and so on..

So do I have that correct?

Seconsly when testing the code above I do not get a break down that matches the actual weighting that I would expect, of roughly every single letter showing up.

Could someone please explain why to the Python newbie in as simple terms as possible?

Comment: What kind of testing have you done? You're only going to see uniform results over a large number of samples. With `k = 9` you're always going to get a new list of 9 elements randomly chosen from your population, but there's nothing about the process that guarantees that you're going to get a perfectly uniform list every time. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: You're specifying cumulative weights. Do you know the difference between cumulative weights and relative weights?

Comment: Oh man I didn't even see that. OP, you've given `a` a probability of 10/100 and the rest a probability of 0!

Comment: All I was fidding around in Jupyter Notebooks testing to see if there was a difference between the two, this is supposed to say 'weights' as I think I have an understanding of that.

Sorry about that!

Ill add I have tested it up to k=1000 and the draw is still off in matching the expected 10% weighting.

Comment: How much off? It won't be _exactly_ 10% each. It's random. Same as if you threw a D10 a thousand times.

Comment: So updated the code to show, but it doesnt begin to hit each of the 10% markers and avoid being significantly off until you get to k = 100,000

Whereas k=100 is ranging between 14% and 4%

Comment: Btw, `Counter(random.choices(population='abcdefghij', weights=[10]*10, k=1000_000))` using `Counter` from `collections`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct understanding of weighting. I'm not sure what your issue is exactly, perhaps your code has errors elsewhere. Another possible error is that `random.choices` does sampling from the population *with replacement*. Read the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). This means that you can sample with k=15 and pull out like 3 `a`s and 0 `b`s.

Here is my code that I used to test, I hope it is useful to you.

```py
import random
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
random.seed(500)

d = defaultdict(int)
sum = 0
# Run this a bunch of times
for _ in range(100000):
    r = random.choices(
        population=[['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e'],['f'],['g'],['h'], ['i'],['j']],
        weights=[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        k=9)
    for ch in r:
        d[ch[0]] += 1
        sum += 1

for k, v in d.items():
    proportion = v/sum
    print(f'{k}: {proportion}')
```

Output

```
h: 0.10035777777777778
j: 0.10031111111111111
f: 0.10043333333333333
c: 0.09983555555555555
d: 0.09992888888888889
i: 0.0998
a: 0.10010222222222222
e: 0.09956555555555556
b: 0.10003222222222222
g: 0.09963333333333334
```

Example run of `random.choices` with replacement on for `k = 15`:

`[['h'], ['j'], ['f'], ['c'], ['h'], ['d'], ['i'], ['d'], ['f'], ['h'], ['a'], ['d'], ['d'], ['c'], ['j']]`

This is totally expected! Brush up on your stats again if you don't understand this.

Edit: Based on the comments on your original post, you should brush up on what the distribution of sampling with replacement looks like. It would be quite surprising if all of the probabilities of the various letters converged on 10% within only 100 samples. I recommend you get a 6 sided die and start rolling while recording what numbers it falls on. It would take quite a few dice throws to get each number with a 1/6 chance according to your samples.